# What does it mean to use ribbon callbacks?

Tags: c#, callback, vsto

I am developing a COM add-in for Excel and I've received a comment that I should use ribbon callbacks.

My code seems to work, so I don't know what the problem is. I have read about callbacks on the Internet, but haven't understood how it pertains to my add-in.

The person who gave me the feedback is a much better programmer than me though, so he is probably right. Maybe you guys know more about what it means to use ribbon callbacks and why I should use it?

Here is an example from my code that reacts to and modifies the ribbon:

```
private void AdxRibbonButton2_OnClick(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
{
    if (CurrentExcelWorksheetEventsInstance.TimerOn == false) {
        //Start Timer
        CurrentExcelWorksheetEventsInstance.TimerStart = Now;
        CurrentExcelWorksheetEventsInstance.TimerOn = true;
        UpdateRibbonTimer(CurrentExcelWorksheetEventsInstance.TimerOn);
    } else {
        //Stop Timer
        NewTableRow(true, Math.Round(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, CurrentExcelWorksheetEventsInstance.TimerStart, Now()) / 60.0 / 60.0, 3));
        CurrentExcelWorksheetEventsInstance.TimerOn = false;
        UpdateRibbonTimer(CurrentExcelWorksheetEventsInstance.TimerOn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth a look: [Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx), start from *Defining the Behavior of the Custom Ribbon*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A callback is a function that executes when the user interacts with the ribbon XML control. The `AdxRibbonButton2_OnClick` function is clearly not a callback. It is probably an event handler since the first parameter is called `sender` and is of type `object`. A callback function for a checkbox or toggle button would like this:

```
public void MyCheckBox_OnAction(IRibbonControl control, bool isPressed)
{
}
```

And in the XML file, the control can be defined like this:

```
<checkBox id="MyCheckBox" onAction="MyCheckBox_OnAction" />
```

In this way, when the checkbox is clicked, the callback is called. Callbacks behave just like event handlers. The difference is that they are bound in the XML file, not in code.

Instead of registering to an event, it would be just a little easier to use callbacks. It is also a little more convenient when using ribbon XML. To register to an event, you need to maintain a reference to the control and you have to write a line of code to manually register event handler. You should use events only when you need to register more than one callback or if you want to unregister a callback or when the callback to be registered is not known until run time.

Comment: Thank you, I almost get it now. Do I need to use callbacks in my code or can I continue coding like I have until now, with event handlers like the one I posed in the question?

Comment: @user1283776 From correctness perspective, both works. However, using callbacks is the standard way in ribbon XML and it makes your code a little more readable for other people who might work on your code in the future. So it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

In computer programming, a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) is a piece of executable code that is passed as an argument to other code, which is expected to call back (execute) the argument at some convenient time. The invocation may be immediate as in a synchronous callback, or it might happen at later time as in an asynchronous callback. In all cases, the intention is to specify a function or subroutine as an entity that is, depending on the language, more or less similar to a variable.

Programming languages support callbacks in different ways, often implementing them with subroutines, lambda expressions, blocks, or function pointers.

As for the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI), you specify the name of function which needs to be called when Office updates the UI and gather new values. Thus, you will be able to specify new values and keep the UI updates. There is no direct properties like Windows Forms provide, all UI updates are made through callbacks.

You can read more about the Ribbon UI (Fluent UI) and callbacks in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)